# AWS CDK How to override default launch configuration in auto scaling group?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-cdk

Hi I am working on AWS CDK. I am creating ECS. I have created auto scaling group as below.

```
autoScallingGroup=asg.AutoScalingGroup(self, id = "auto scalling", vpc= vpc, machine_image=ecs.EcsOptimizedImage.amazon_linux(), desired_capacity=1, key_name="mws-location", max_capacity=1, min_capacity=1, instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t2.xlarge"))
```

This will generate default launch configuration also. I want to write my own launch configuration for this auto scaling group.

Can someone help me to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific construct to create a launch configuration in CDK. However, you can construct one by passing in arguments to aws_autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup constructor.

You need to specifiy the following attributes of AutoScalingGroup class:

- role
- instance_type
- key_name
- machine_image
- user_data
- associate_public_ip_address
- block_devices

You can also add security groups using the `add_security_group()` function.

For example, if you want to add user data to the LaunchConfig:

```
userdata = ec2.UserData.for_linux(shebang="#!/bin/bash -xe")
userdata.add_commands(
         "echo '======================================================='",
         "echo \"ECS_CLUSTER=${MWSServiceCluster}\" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config"
)

asg = autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(
        self,
        "asg-identifier",
        ...
        user_data=userdata,
)
```

Comment: Thanks. How to specify user data? I have something like this  userdata = 'Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          echo "================================================================================="
          echo ECS_CLUSTER=${MWSServiceCluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config'

Comment: Do I need to create aws_cdk.aws_ec2.UserData construct?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer with a sample userdata.

Comment: Hi In launch configuration I have ImageId(When I was writing cloud formation). Here how can I specify?

Comment: machine_image = ec2.AmazonLinuxImage(). Check the module documentation for some examples: https://pypi.org/project/aws-cdk.aws-ec2/

Comment: I added above but in launch configuration we have some field imageid so these both are same or different?

Comment: there is an example in the module docs that I posted. linux = ec2.GenericLinuxImage({ "us-east-1": "ami-97785bed"})